# Simple Kriging with linear semivariogram

Tags: spatial, variogram, geostatistics, kriging

While studying how to develop a simple kriging model with a linear semivariogram, the various tutorials point towards creating a covariogram using $\sigma(h) = \sigma(0) - \gamma(h)$, but the value of $\sigma(0) \to \infty$ (i.e. the sill of the semivarigram) for a linear semivariogram.

So, how does one go about proceeding with a simple kriging model using a linear semivariogram (the variogram has been constructed by me using regression)?
(i.e. How does one go about evaluating the covarigram using the above equations or does one use a different set of equations for Kriging with linear semivariograms?) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The nature of this question is not apparent.  Is it about estimating the slope and nugget of the variogram, cross-validating the variogram, choosing appropriate search procedures, setting up the kriging equations, solving the kriging equations, or something else?  Please edit this post to explain what you mean by "developing."

Comment: @whuber Edited the question. I have evaluated the linear variogram (slope, nugget = $\gamma (0)$). But with the evaluated variogram, I am not able to find the sill to be used for evaluating the covariogram (mentioned in the question); as a result of which I can not find the value of $\sigma(0)$, which is the sill (it $\to \infty$ for linear semivariograms).

Comment: There is no sill: that is the entire point of using variograms instead of covariance functions. In the absence of any nugget effect or measurement error, necessarily $\gamma(0)=0$ and the variogram has the form $\gamma(h)=\rho h$ for some positive $\rho$.

Comment: @whuber That is very true. And hence I put up this question, since the Kriging tutorials ask to create a semivariogram and then construct a covariogram [Page6](http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~chris/Lecture13_210C_Spring2011_ModelSemivariograms.pdf), after which the covariance matrix is constructed. When a new point is to be interpolated(kriged), this matrix is used for finding the value at the given point. 
Thus, how does one calculate the $\sigma (0)$ for the covariogram computation. I could not search for any online references to this; I will be really thankful for your answer to this.

Comment: It's just like the Ordinary Kriging system but without the Lagrange multipliers.  Much of the online material on kriging is awful--you have to search hard to find anything good--so it's usually better to consult one of the more reputable textbooks.  The material from NKU at http://ceadserv1.nku.edu/longa//modules/geostats/lec/latex2html/node1.html seems good, though.

Comment: @whuber What textbook would you suggest? 
Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Cressie, *Statistics for Spatial Data*, is now a classic reference.

Answer (score 1):

The linear variogram does not have a covariance equivalence, because it continues increasing to infinity. If you need to work with the linear variograms (or with variograms that have no sill in general), use ordinary kriging.